# does react-native have autoCompleteDropdown?

Tags: android, react-native, autocomplete, dropdown

how is it possible to implement a native [autocompletetextview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) for react native with java?

how come you don't have any?

Answer (score 0):

You can make you custom component for the same, by calling the api on changetext of text input and on `modal` you have a **`flatlist`** to render the response for the same. But then in this case you have to cancel the fetch call of the previous state if user enters the text very fast otherwise you will end up calling the server many times.

> Alternatively you can use the libaries below:
>   1. http://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input
>   2. https://github.com/maxkordiyak/react-native-dropdown-autocomplete

I hope this helps...Thanks :)

Comment: i had seen these. it's not what i want. i have made it with modal and flatlist, it's not useful

Comment: as per your question, this is the best what you get...What you want btw ?

Comment: @Gray try first one (Recently I have used with Webservice data)